# How to convert Perforce depot locations to client view locations

Tags: view, mapping, client, perforce

I'd like to know how to convert Perforce depot locations to client view locations for the purpose of script writing.

I have a script that first checks out a file for edit in perforce and then interacts with the file.   I need to have the depot location (i.e. \Projects\Project6) converted to the client view location.  (i.e. d:\Projects\Project6).

Is this possible?

Comment: perforce is the worst.

Answer (score 11):

I have always used the **p4 where** command for this. Here is its description from the built-in help:

> ```
> where -- Show how file names map through the client view
>
> p4 where [ file ... ]
>
>     Where shows how the named files map through the client view.
>     For each argument, three names are produced: the name in the
>     depot, the name on the client in Perforce syntax, and the name
>     on the client in local syntax.
>
>     If no file is given, the mapping for '...' (all files in the
>     current directory and below) is shown.
>
>     Note that 'p4 where' does not determine where any real files are.
>     It only computes where they should be according to the client view.
> ```

Comment: If you want to parse the output of `p4 where` and your filenames have spaces in them, see http://maillist.perforce.com/pipermail/perforce-user/2007-February/020820.html - I found something like `p4 where -T quack //blah/somefile.txt` worked well. The `quack` part just gets quoted in the output but you have to put something there. Also, since `p4 where` can output multiple results for complex workspaces (see Usage Notes under http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_where.html), make sure you only take the last interesting line from the output (I think this is safe).

Answer (score 4):

I would use the **p4 fstat** command. I find its format slightly easier to parse than **p4 have**. Additionally if you are scripting this in python you can use the [-G option](http://kb.perforce.com/ToolsScripts/UsingP4G) to have the the return values marshalled as python dictionaries.

It is also useful to note that you can type **p4 help commands** to see a list of the commands and a short description of what they do.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `p4 have` command. You give it *either* a depot location *or* a client filename and it gives you the depot location, client filename, *and* what version of that file you have.